# Bad expiration date format, and this expiration date will be ignored

Tags: soa, jdeveloper, bpel

I have created a BPEL process with wait activity, there are input for process start time (datetime) and interval(duration). while creating an instance(workitem) in process, it moves to wait and on console i got the error

```
<Mar 23, 2011 9:27:53 PM SGT> <Error> <oracle.soa.bpel.engine.bpel> <BEA-000000>
 <<BPELReceiveWMP::__defineExpirationDate> Bad expiration date format, and this
expiration date will be ignored
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Duration has to start with 'P'.
```

Input payload for process is:

```
<inputVariable>  <part  name="payload">  <ns1:process>  <ns1:startDate>2011-03-23T16:30:00.000+08:00</ns1:startDate>  <ns1:interval>PT2M</ns1:interval>  </ns1:process>  </part>  </inputVariable>
```

And in wait have putted

> string(bpws:getVariableData('inputVariable','payload','/client:process/client:startDate'))

expression in "for" column

*WaitForStart (pending) 
Mar 23, 2011 9:27:53 PM Bad expiration date "2011-03-23T16:30:00.000+08:00" 
Mar 23, 2011 9:27:53 PM Waiting for the expiry time "never".*

environment is: 
SOA 11.1.1.3.0
Jdeveloper: 11.3

Answer (score 1):

If the input is "2011-03-23T16:30:00.000+08:00 PT2M" the problem is quite clear. The first part is dateTime while the second part is a duration. The  element in BPEL expects a duration, so its value should be just "PT2M", which means 2 minutes. The first part of the string looks erroneous to me.

Comment: Sorry my mistake I did not post the question in proper format,now please check.... now we can see the payload xml for input having two inputs one for time and another for duration.

Comment: Okee, but it still looks like your using the value of the client:startDate element as a duration. Shouldn't it be client:interval for the "for" value?